# How to run CoAP (er-rest-example) on CC2650 sensortag without Border Router?

Tags: rest, contiki, coap

I want to run simple client-server of er-rest-example on CC2650 Sensortags without border router. Purpose is to test coap transactions.

All the details in readme and wiki involves border router. Any help for running coap without border router will be highly appreciated.

I complied and ran er-rest-client and er-rest-server on sensortags but client transactions timeout and RPL DIS does not get processed.

Comment: I don't immediately see any reason why your approach does not work. Asking here might help with the debugging: https://gitter.im/contiki-ng/Developers

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether this should be a comment or an answer, but since I lack the reputation to comment, here it goes:

Neither er-rest-client nor er-rest-server set up a mesh network for RPL, which is why the examples include a border router that does that. If you go into core/net/ip/tcpip.c and enable DEBUG, I'm guessing you see the following ouput:

```
tcpip_ipv6_output: no route found, using default route
tcpip_ipv6_output: Destination off-link but no route
```

For a similar project I'm working on, adding the following lines to the server process solved that problem:

```
root_if = uip_ds6_addr_lookup(&ipaddr);
if(root_if != NULL){
  rpl_dag_t* dag;
  dag = rpl_set_root(RPL_DEFAULT_INSTANCE, (uip_ip6addr_t*)&ipaddr);
  uip_ip6addr(&ipaddr, UIP_DS6_DEFAULT_PREFIX, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
  rpl_set_prefix(dag, &ipaddr, 64);
  printf("created new RPL dag\n");
}
else{
  printf("RPL dag creation failed\n");
}
```

You will need to also include "net/rpl/rpl.h" and declare a variable "struct uip_ds6_addr* root_if"
That code is extracted from the ipv6/rpl examples provided by contiki.